# ACF odd/even repeater

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to create a two column element using ACF repeater fields. The only thing is I'm trying to alternate this so that the content in the two columns switches left/right depending on the row being even or odd.

The output will look something like:

> Row 1: Image (left column), Description (right column)
>
> Row 2: Description (left column), Image (right column)
>
> Row 3: Image (left column), Description (right column)
>
> Row 4: Description (left column), Image (right column)
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .

This is how I looped it:

```
<section id="projects" class="container specific-margin-1">
        <div class="row specific-padding-4">
            <div class="container col-lg-12">
                <center><h2>FEATURED PROJECTS</h2></center>
            </div><!-- col-lg-12  --> 
        </div><!-- row  -->

            <!-- Repeater --> 
            <div class="row">
            <?php $row = 0; //<-- set your counter to 0
                        if(get_field('featured_projects')): ?>
            <?php while(has_sub_field('featured_projects')): ?>

                <?php if ($counter % 2 === 0) :?>
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- right column -->
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-6">
                        <img src="<?php the_sub_field('project_image'); ?>" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                            <?php the_sub_field('project_details'); ?>
                    </div><!-- right column -->
                </div>

                <?php else: ?>

                <div class="row">
                    <!-- left column -->
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                        <?php the_sub_field('project_details'); ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-6">
                        <img src="<?php the_sub_field('project_image'); ?>" />
                    </div><!-- left column -->
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php $row++; endwhile; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- Repeater -->
    </section>
```

Comment: If you are using bootstrap it would probably be better to have each row's html the same. Then add offset classes the the odd rows' columns. This way things will stack nicely on mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to change your ACF Image field to 'Image Array':

[ACF Image Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTKXI.jpg)

```html
<!-- Repeater -->
<div class="row">
  <?php $i=0 ; if(get_field( 'featured_projects')): ?>
  <?php while(has_sub_field( 'featured_projects')): $i++; ?>
  <?php $image=get_sub_field( 'project_image'); ?>
  <div class="row">
    <!-- right column -->
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-6">
      <?php if (($i % 2)==0 ): ?>
      <?php the_sub_field( 'project_details'); ?>
      <?php else: ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" />
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <?php if (($i % 2)==0 ): ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" />
      <?php else: ?>
      <?php the_sub_field( 'project_details'); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <!-- right column -->
  </div>

  <?php endwhile; ?>

  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<!-- Repeater -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: But, how do I actually alternate the size of the column as well?

Comment: You could do something like this:

`<div class="<?php if (($i % 2)==0 ): ?>col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-6<?php else: ?>col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6<?php endif; ?>">` and switch the classes around on the div below.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for simplest answer (To divide the rows in odd/even), We can use the get_row_index() function to check current row.

Code format should be like this:

```
while( have_rows('featured_projects') ): the_row();

    if( get_row_index() % 2 == 0 ){
        
        // this is an even row
        
    } else {
        
        // this is an odd row
        
    }

endwhile;
```